# Obj-c Arrays for coordinates - best practices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have recently begun teaching myself Obj-c and have undertaken a large project in order to learn the principles of the language as they come up. I am making a game with a 14 tile board. Now in placing these I felt it best to put the coordinates for each tile in a .plist, access this info and then return out each coordinate. so the plist looks something like this:

root ---> position on board ---> item 0 ---> TileX (number(4)), Tile y (number(12)) ---> item 1 ...etc. etc. up to 13.

Now in code I have this as

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"WheelData.plist"];
NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
NSArray *positionOnBoard = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[plistData objectForKey:@"Position On Board"]];

int numberOfPositions = [positionOnBoard count];

NSMutableArray *PositionX;
NSMutableArray *PositionY;
NSMutableArray *arrayOfPositionsX = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberOfPositions];
NSMutableArray *arrayOfPositionsY = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberOfPositions];
for (int d = 0; d < numberOfPositions; d++) {
    [arrayOfPositionsX addObject:[[positionOnBoard objectAtIndex:d] objectForKey:@"Tile X"]];
    [arrayOfPositionsY addObject:[[positionOnBoard objectAtIndex:d] objectForKey:@"Tile Y"]];
    PositionX = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayOfPositionsX];
    PositionY = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayOfPositionsY];

    if (d == 0) {
        NSLog(@"%i %@ %@", d, arrayOfPositionsX, arrayOfPositionsY);
    } else if (d == 1) {
        [arrayOfPositionsX removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [arrayOfPositionsY removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%i %@ %@", d, arrayOfPositionsX, arrayOfPositionsY);
    } else if (d == 2) {
        [arrayOfPositionsX removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [arrayOfPositionsY removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%i %@ %@", d, arrayOfPositionsX, arrayOfPositionsY);
    } else if (d == 3) {
        [arrayOfPositionsX removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [arrayOfPositionsY removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%i %@ %@", d, arrayOfPositionsX, arrayOfPositionsY);
    } else if (d == 4) {
        [arrayOfPositionsX removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [arrayOfPositionsY removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%i %@ %@", d, arrayOfPositionsX, arrayOfPositionsY);
    } else if (d == 5) {
        [arrayOfPositionsX removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [arrayOfPositionsY removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%i %@ %@", d, arrayOfPositionsX, arrayOfPositionsY);
    } else if (d == 6) {
        [arrayOfPositionsX removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [arrayOfPositionsY removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%i %@ %@", d, arrayOfPositionsX, arrayOfPositionsY);
    } else if (d == 7) {
        [arrayOfPositionsX removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [arrayOfPositionsY removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%i %@ %@", d, arrayOfPositionsX, arrayOfPositionsY);
    } else if (d == 8) {
        [arrayOfPositionsX removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [arrayOfPositionsY removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%i %@ %@", d, arrayOfPositionsX, arrayOfPositionsY);
    } else if (d == 9) {
        [arrayOfPositionsX removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [arrayOfPositionsY removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%i %@ %@", d, arrayOfPositionsX, arrayOfPositionsY);
    } else if (d == 10) {
        [arrayOfPositionsX removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [arrayOfPositionsY removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%i %@ %@", d, arrayOfPositionsX, arrayOfPositionsY);
    } else if (d == 11) {
        [arrayOfPositionsX removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [arrayOfPositionsY removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%i %@ %@", d, arrayOfPositionsX, arrayOfPositionsY);
    } else if (d == 12) {
        [arrayOfPositionsX removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [arrayOfPositionsY removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%i %@ %@", d, arrayOfPositionsX, arrayOfPositionsY);
    } else {
        [arrayOfPositionsX removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [arrayOfPositionsY removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%i %@ %@", d, arrayOfPositionsX, arrayOfPositionsY);
    }

}
return PositionX;
return PositionY;
```

Now obviously at the moment I am just nslogging this so i am getting each tile to return both its X value and Y value. I will eventually plot this on to some sort of CGRectMake grid and then use images to show this on the viewcontroller. As i said i am new to this and still learning. Are there simpler ways to do this? Better ways? I would really appreciate the feedback, thank you!

Comment: This question might be better at StackExchange - where more general programming discussions occur. AFAIK, StackOverflow is for solving specific problems. . . having said that, why not create a rich model that represents your game's concepts? Ie Have a **Board** that's composed with a set of **Positions**? You can then use the ActiveRecord or DAO pattern to load this model from persistent storage (flat-file, local db, cloud, etc).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you need to be able to do with the tiles.  Are they always in a fixed grid layout (for example 2 rows of 7 columns), but the locations of the individual tiles change?  If that's the case then it might be simpler to use a 2-dimensional array of ints to hold the layout of the game board.  Or maybe the tiles can move anywhere in space so you need exact X and Y coordinates?  In that case, you might consider storing the X and Y coordinates (and the size) in an NSRect, because that will save you a step when it comes time to draw the tiles.

Comment: Ah sorry should have explained it better! These coordinates represent the centre point of hexagon images(maybe objects later as they have attributes), so there will be 14 hexagons set in place on a grid. Now i need to do this rather than just make a background image as these tiles can have an affect on gameplay depending on the selected rules. I'm not sure if that actually clarifies anything. :)

Comment: Note that every time through your for loop you are making a copy of `arrayOfPositionsX` and `arrayOfPositionsY`, but not doing anything with them, which has little purpose.

Comment: my plan is was to return the tile number and the x and y positions as one piece of information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply add a string of positions into your plist file in the format {10,10}....
So your plist structure would look like this;

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>{10,10}</string>
    <string>{10,10}</string>
    <string>{10,10}</string>
    <string>{10,10}</string>
    <string>{10,10}</string>
    <string>{10,10}</string>
    <string>{10,10}</string>
    <string>{10,10}</string>
    <string>{10,10}</string>
    <string>{10,10}</string>
    <string>{10,10}</string>
    <string>{10,10}</string>
    <string>{10,10}</string>
    <string>{10,10}</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

Then, access the data as below;

```
NSArray *positionsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Page" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

The above array will hold all the positions in `NSString` format. You can generate a `CGPoint` from these NSStrings. 
You can directly use these CGPoints to position your tiles or you can even separate out X and Y coordinates as per your need. Please find the code snippet below;

```
int count = 0;
for(NSString *strPos in positionsArray)
{
    count++;
    CGPoint position = CGPointFromString(strPos);
    NSLog(@"Position %d -> X:%f Y:%f",count,position.x,position.y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from your comment above:

I'm assuming the grid is hexagonal too, so it would be rows of 2, 3, 4, 3, and 2 to equal 14 tiles. If it's a grid and the physical position of the tiles will always be one of the discrete positions in the grid, I don't think you need to store the X and Y coordinates for each tile.  You can store their position within the grid in a 2-dimensional array and have a method that draws the board and puts the tiles in their corresponding place within the grid.  In addition to that, it doesn't make much sense to store the center X and Y coordinates of each tile (unless you need to for some reason).  Since drawing coordinates start at the bottom left, you should think of each hexagon as existing within a rectangle and store the bottom left X and Y coordinates.  Obviously, the rows of rectangles will need to overlap a bit in order for the tiles to fit snugly together (if my assumption about the grid is right).

At the very least, you should rethink that `for` loop in your code.  Having an `if` statement for each iteration defeats the purpose of a `for` loop and is totally unnecessary considering that each `else if` statement does the exact same thing.  You could clean it up to look like this:

```
for (int d = 0; d < numberOfPositions; d++) {
    [arrayOfPositionsX addObject:[[positionOnBoard objectAtIndex:d] objectForKey:@"Tile X"]];
    [arrayOfPositionsY addObject:[[positionOnBoard objectAtIndex:d] objectForKey:@"Tile Y"]];
    PositionX = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayOfPositionsX];
    PositionY = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayOfPositionsY];

    if (d == 0) {
        NSLog(@"%i %@ %@", d, arrayOfPositionsX, arrayOfPositionsY);
    } else {
        [arrayOfPositionsX removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [arrayOfPositionsY removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%i %@ %@", d, arrayOfPositionsX, arrayOfPositionsY);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct in the grid shape, i'm looking at my hand drawn picture of the grid with the hexagons on it and it is indeed 2,3,4,3,2. I was always thinking of rows and columns as a square or rectangular table but this makes a lot of sense with my project. I didn't realise that the drawing coordinates started at bottom left, thats really good to know! Also took your advice about the for loop works without all the else if statements!

Comment: I should also say that what the `for` loop does is unnecessary (as someone noted above), because you're adding an object to an array, `NSLog`ing it, then removing it immediately.

Comment: Like in the original code, `PositionX` and `PositionY` aren't doing anything. There is no need for that code.